# ImageResizer diskcache System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, imageresizer, diskcache

The following exception is logged in our application:

> System.IO.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete
>   the requested service. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.FlushOSBuffer() at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk) at
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0()
>   at ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key,
>   Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success) at
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String
>   keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, Int32
>   timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous) at
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e) at
>   ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context,
>   IResponseArgs e) at
>   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.HandleRequest(HttpContext context,
>   HttpModuleRequestAssistant ra, IVirtualFile vf) at
>   ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

We have a load balanced environment with two web servers using the same cache folder on a separate file server.

Our diskcache configuration is like this:

```
<diskcache dir="~/imageresizercache" autoClean="true" hashModifiedDate="true" />
```

Any idea why we get this exception?
Thanks,

Comment: That is a very unusual mishap, never seen it before.  The underlying OS call (FlushFileBuffers) does not have a lot of good reasons to run out of memory.  Do suspect an anti-malware product being anti.  And keep an eye on the OS kernel memory pool statistics, this is not cheap code and having too many clients hitting your web sever at the same time does have a knack for bringing it to its knees.  Consider a static Semaphore to limit the number of concurrent calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share the diagnostics page? /resizer.debug

It sounds like there is a bottleneck connected to the shared file server. Generally it is best to disable autoClean if the cache files are not stored locally.

Comment: We change to local storage for our web servers and this exception is not thrown anymore. Also some CPU spikes stopped from the same moment we changed. Thanks for your help.